Is it possible to use different Python interpreters for Git submodules in PyCharm?
I’m working on a project in PyCharm that includes several Git submodules. Each submodule has its own requirements, so I need to use a different Python interpreter
Is there a way to set up PyCharm so that it automatically uses the correct interpreter depending on the submodule I’m working in?
In VS Code, you can handle this by adding each submodule as a separate workspace and assigning a specific interpreter to each. Does PyCharm have anything similar?

In terms of the IntelliJ platform, PyCharm is a single-module IDE, so you only have one module per project and thus only one SDK/interpreter. Most JetBrains IDEs work this way, except for the multi-module IntelliJ IDEA, which does support your use case.

why not create a runner script which sets PATH variable and then execute the python script/module? So effectively I am suggesting to run directly from command line instead of from IDE. Now, you are free to configure as per your requirement

@AnubhavSharma Good idea, but I need dynamic interpreter switching in PyCharm for code analysis and autocomplete. Your solution skips that, which defeats the point of using an IDE.

In the Run debug configurations (top corner right) you can specify the "python interpreter" for each run/debug setting as well as env variables, flags, paths, entry points and many other things.
You can use a tool such as poetry to create and manage the different environments, but even that can be managed from the IDE.

That’s a good suggestion, but it doesn’t fully solve my issue. I’m looking for a way to have PyCharm automatically switch interpreters based on the Git submodule I’m working in, not just manually set them for specific run/debug configurations.

I think the best way will be opening three windows, each at one submodule. take into account that there is only one globally interpreter. I use a lot sub-modules and they tend to have a subset of the global dependencies, in that case you get all the benefits by taking an interpreter with the superset of all dependencies as global interpreter, no need to do weird things just for sub-modules. If your sub-modules have incompatible dependencies then probably they should not be sub-modules :)

Good point, but honestly, I’d expect a $99/year IDE like PyCharm to have built-in support for dynamic interpreter switching.

Opening separate windows for 10+ submodules, like AWS Lambda handlers, isn’t practical. And saying incompatible dependencies mean they shouldn’t be submodules misses the point—submodules are just linked repos for better organization. Splitting them into 10 standalone repos would be a maintenance nightmare)

Well, I use the community edition which is 100% free and open source, so i can´t complain much, it could be developed by anyone at any time. Maybe you? good luck in any case.

Thanks dude, think I'll get around to it someday, but definitely not right now, good luck to you.
